# Why RStudio is not picking up environment variables defined in $HOME/.bashrc

Tags: bash, boot, environment-variables, desktop-environment, profile

I use Arch Linux.

I use SSDM as display manager, but I have disabled it with:

```
sudo systemctl disable sddm
```

I have put code in `/etc/profile`, `$HOME/.bash_profile` and `$HOME/.bashrc` to echo when those files are sourced.

My `$HOME/.bash_profile` is sourcing `$HOME/.bashrc` (it came like that, I just added the code to echo when this happens):

```
if [[ -f ~/.bashrc ]]; then
    echo "$HOME/.bash_profile is sourcing $HOME/.bashrc"
    . ~/.bashrc
fi
```

I am exporting the following variable in my `$HOME/.bashrc`:

```
export R_LIBS_USER='MY_VALUE'
```

---

I boot my PC.

It shows a prompt (in a TUI/command line) that asks for username and then password.

I put them in and press enter.

`/etc/profile` is source.
`$HOME/.bash_profile` is source.
The latter sources `$HOME/.bashrc`.
This means that `R_LIBS_USER` is being exported.

I'm redirected to a prompt.

I do:

```
sudo systemctl start ssdm
```

Since SSDM is a child of that shell, it should inherit `R_LIBS_USER`.

SSDM opens and I start a Wayland KDE session.

Since this session is a child of SSDM, it should inherit `R_LIBS_USER`.

I open RStudio from KDE.

But `R_LIBS_USER` is still at the default value, not the one I have defined in `$HOME/.bashrc`.

I show the value of the variable in R with:

```
Sys.getenv("R_LIBS_USER")
```

Where is my reasoning failing?

Comment: Your window manager may use `$HOME/.profile`. Try adding your environment variables to that file (with POSIX shell syntax), and then `$HOME/.bash_profile` can source it.

Comment: @glennjackman nope doesn't work

Comment: You may need to read the ssdm documentation to figure out what dotfiles it uses.

Comment: If it uses PAM, try `$HOME/.pam_environment`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since SSDM is a child of that shell,

No, it's not. It's getting started by systemd (so, the process formerly known as `init`) as instructed by `systemctl`.

So, that's where your chain breaks.

Comment: How comes that systemd was formerly known as `init`?

Comment: The process that the kernel  spawned to start services used to be `init` of system V heritage (so: older than I am). These days, on most Linux systems for the desktop and medium sized embedded devices it's systems. It's definitely on your system - you can use systemctl to start services :)

Comment: By "systems" you mean "systemd"?

Comment: Jep, sorry,typo